# alert links inside iframe with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to alert both links (inside iframe) with class search if I click on Search button.

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO</title>
  </head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body>
    <div id="btn">
      <button id="btn-search">Search</button>
    </div>
    <div class="iframebox">
      <iframe id="messageiframe">
       #document

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <head>
          <title>test</title>
        </head>

        <body>
          <div id="textpreview">
            <p id="pre">some text</p>
          </div>

          <div id="preview">
            <ul id="list">
              <li class="mail"><a href="https://mail.gmail.com">Gmail</a></li>
              <li class="search"><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li class="mail"><a href="https://mail.outlook.com">Outlook</a></li>
              <li class="search"><a href="https://www.bing.com">Bing</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </body>

        </html>
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is my jQuery code that I tried but it's not working:

```
$('#btn-search').on('click', function() {
  var links = [];
  var t = $("#messageiframe").contents().find("#preview");
  var link = '';
  t.find('li.search').children('a').each(function() {
    link += $(this).text();
  });
  links.push(link);
  alert(links);
});
```

and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxfd5gb5/3/)

Comment: can you please tell me what you need exactly ?

Comment: This is just an example, the code between `iframe` tags actually is placed in another file, isn't it?

Comment: yes, you are right @Teemu.

Comment: Please define "_not working_". What does the code alert?

Comment: alerts nothing, just blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the contents of an `iframe`, use the following :

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('messageiframe');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

From within the documents to filter out based on classes or ID use [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) or [`.getElementsById()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) functions. Here we use,

```
innerDoc.getElementsByClassName("search")
```

Then use the filtered list of objects and work with them as you wish using JQuery. And voila, alerts are working!

See working **solution** here: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rhk217/thvc2nqt/)

Note that there were some errors in the question, like directly including code within `iframe`. Use [`srcdoc`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp) attribute of `iframes` for that. They have been rectified in the solution Fiddle. But since you are using html from another file, no need to ponder more on that.

Comment: Please mark it as the right answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rithwik.